# Which plugin for identifying crypto algorithms in IDA Pro 6.9?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, cryptography

I stumbled upon findcrypt2 but it seems not to work anymore. Is there a new version of findcryp2 anywhere or are there similar plugins which are able to identify different crypto algorithms by checking specific constants etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Try [IDAsignsrch](http://www.macromonkey.com/ida-signsrch-released/), or the original [commandline version](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm).

Comment: Does it work for anyone here on Mac OS X El Capitan? Either I'm too stupid to get it running or it's not working on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to recommend [IDAScope](https://bitbucket.org/daniel_plohmann/simplifire.idascope) but it is broken in 6.9 as well. 
PySide has been dropped by IDA in favor of PyQT in 6.9.

Edit: 
Thanks to Daniel Plohmann, the plugin now supports IDA 6.9. 
You can see the fixed code here: [committed 2fdeed1](https://bitbucket.org/daniel_plohmann/simplifire.idascope/commits/2fdeed1644ed39b81bf7b27d2cc33f8318787875)

Comment: I will be looking into the necessary adaptions to make IDAscope work with PyQt instead of PySide in the next two weeks. :)

Comment: Thanks @pnx for updating the plugin.
Edited my comment above.